# From where does the radiation come from in an inverse-Bremsstrahlung process?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, radiation

I'm trying to know more about Bremsstrahlung and inverse-Bremsstrahlung processes. If you know any good references that treat theses topics with a good mathematical and physical basis, please let me know.

I understood that in  a Bremsstrahlung process a charged particle emits radiation when interacting with another one (for example an electron and a positive ion), since the interaction causes an acceleration, and any accelerated charged particle emits radiation. The radiation would come from the particles, causing a loss of kinetic energy. 
I also discovered that an absorption of radiation can also occur in such process, being the name of that process an "inverse-Bremsstrahlung". In such case where does the radiation come from? Does it simply come from the background? It seems that too many ingredients need to be in harmony so that such process can happen.

Comment: Does it matter? Bremsstrahlung happens when matter is bombarded with high-energy electrons. Inverse Bremsstrahlung happens when matter is bombarded with high-energy photons. You don't need to know the nature of the source in order to know that the process happens.

Comment: That's the engineering view. I would like to know the physical counterpart instead: I would like to know how it happens.

Comment: That's the physics view, the engineering one would be what type of machine to build to do that